# Using uint16_t and char* with QMetaObject::invokeMethod()

Tags: c++, qt

I want to invoke a slot asynchronously from a different thread using [QMetaObject::invokeMethod()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)

The class containing the slot is declared as:

```
class Paintable : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  [...]
  public slots:
    void drawString(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t size, const char* str, color c);
}
```

and the method that calls invokeMethod is defined as:

```
void drawStringAsynchronously(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t size, const char* str, color c) {
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(paintable,
               "drawString",
               Qt::QueuedConnection,
               Q_ARG(uint16_t, x), Q_ARG(uint16_t, y), Q_ARG(uint16_t, size),
               Q_ARG(const char*, str), Q_ARG(color, c));
}
```

(where `paintable` is of type `Paintable*`)

But Qt seems to be unable to use uint16_t or char* in invokeMethod because at runtime I get the following message:

`QMetaMethod::invoke: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'const char*'`

and

`QMetaMethod::invoke: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'uint16_t'`

respectively.

I was able to successfully register my custom struct `color` using `qRegisterMetaType()` but since `uint16_t` and `char*` are no structs or classes this won't work.

I'd be very glad if somebody could show me how to do it or show a good alternative.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(...)` macro anyway?

Comment: @cmannett85: I'm using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` _and_ `qRegisterMetaType()` for my custom `color` type like stated in the docs. But this won't work for non-structs or non-classes.

Comment: Did you actually try registering those types as metatypes?  This will work.

Comment: @DanMilburn: I tried it once again and it didn't work using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(char*);` but seems to work using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(const char*);`. Unfortunately it still won't work for `uint16_t` or `const uint16_t`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with registering uint16_t is this:  It's a typedef, and Qt has already registered this type, but it's under a different name.  Since the QMetaType system is based on determining types by their name this causes problems.

You can get around this with:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(uint16_t)
```

then:

```
qRegisterMetaType<uint16_t>("uint16_t");
```

This creates an alias so that metatypes can be created with that name.